# Рейтинг пользователя и права доступа на wordpress

Tags: cms, php, wordpress, плагин, javascript

Доброго времени, уважаемые профессионалы!

Задачка творческая, хотя, наверняка, кто-либо из вас ее уже не раз решал.

Дано: закрытый паролем сайт. Регестрируясь на котором пользователь должен получить доступ к первой статье и видео. На следующий день открывается вторая, еще через сутки - третья и тд.

То есть, в зависимости от даты его регистрации, ему должны открываться определенные статьи сайта. Как это возможно реализовать? Есть ли готовое решение в виде плагина?

Я себе это вижу как некий внутренний рейтинг пользователя, но как технически сделать понятия не имею. Скажите хоть куда копать?

Comment: На псевдокоде:

    если (не зарегистрирован ИЛИ дата - дата регистрации < порог открытия материала) {
        закрыть_доступ()
    }
    // обычный вывод

Answer (score 1):

Для решения вашей задачи могу посоветовать почитать следующее:
 [Данные пользователя](http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC/wp_insert_user) и [Дата публикации поста](http://wp-kama.ru/function/the_date)

Схема:

1. Пользователь залогинен? Если да, то продолжаем алгоритм
2. 1. Получаем дату его регистрации
3. 1. Получаем дату публикации статьи
4. Сравниваем дату публикации, если она позже то продолжаем алгоритм
5. Публикуем статью

Если не залогинен, то говорим залогиниться

Если дата публикации позже даты регистрации, то пишем, что недорос ещё

(Пока что на работе, не могу реализовать кодом, буду дома, может и код напишу)

Comment: Кода получилось не мало, на какой сайт его можно выложить?(я забыл)

Comment: @cema93, http://pastebin.com http://ideone.com и http://gist.github.com (последний требует регистрации на гитхабе, насколько понимаю)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ky28bCSp
тестить, к сожалению, возможности нет, но должно работать.
Делал на основе стандартной темы